# Safari ignoring tabindex

Tags: safari, accessibility

I have 2 buttons next to a textbox and another textbox after the 2 buttons.  The tabindex for the first textbox is 1000, the first button is 1001 and the second button is 1002.  The second textbox has a tabindex of 1003.

When I press tab, the tabindex works fine in all browsers except for Safari, where it immediately moves from the first textbox to the second textbox although the tabindex has been set properly.  Any ideas on how to prevent this issue?

Comment: If you remove the second textarea and switch the button tabindexes (so the order in the source is 1000, 1002, 1001), does Safari follow the tabindex order? Looks like Safari gives higher precedence to textareas/text inputs, for whatever reason...

Comment: No, even that doesn't work.  It seems as if tabindex on href's are ignored in Safari.  I am trying a workaround with buttons to see if that will work.

Comment: This is not how tabindex works. The only relevant numbers for tabindex are -1, 0, and 1. The rest are an anti-pattern and may break accessibility for users.

Answer (score 267):

By default tab-access is disabled in safari(!). To enable it, check "Preferences > Advanced > Press tab to highlight each item on a page".

Comment: This answer is almost 7 years old, but it's still the correct fix. I'm surprised Apple doesn't enable this option by default.

Comment: This is unbelievable. Why would Safari DO this?

Comment: Is there a way to do this on iPad? I don't see this option under Settings -> Safari -> Advanced. Let me know if you know how to do this on iPad please.

Comment: @Chemist I'm not sure how you would use a TAB key on an iPad, or why?

Comment: @graphicdivine I figured it out, you have to use Options+Tab. How - with bluetooth keyboard, why - because the job requires it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292016/is-there-a-workaround-to-safaris-operas-bug-that-you-cant-tab-through-hyperli

Comment: Yes it seems like tabbing works by default as long as you hold down option.

Comment: The behavior is the same in iOS safari but I cannot find a similar option there.  Does anyone know how to enable this on Safari for iOS?

Comment: I hate that safari has these kind of problems. I have to keep telling my users to use Google chrome or Firefox because I can't configure push notifications without paying a 100 USD per year, although I have a reset.css file, my styles don't look good on safari (just for little things like margins), tab does not work without doing some difficult thing for a normal user.

Comment: The same thing for Chrome. Go to Settings → Appearance → Pressing Tab on a web page highlights links, as well as form fields

Comment: @Londeren the difference is this setting is checked by default on Chrome.

Comment: Thank you. I was getting frustrated. I could tab through everything in Chrome.  In Safari, I could tab through links and input fields with or without tabindex="0" added to them. But Safari skipped over buttons without links. I tried your tip and now I can tab through everything in Safari.

Answer (score 32):

Solution for iOS will be holding Option Key + Tab key.

Answer (score 23):

Making Safari and a Mac accessible:

Testing on a Mac:
System Preferences  -> Keyboard -> ShortCuts (tab) -> Full Keyboard Access -> All Controls

For Tabbing to work on Safari:
Preferences -> Advanced -> Press tab to highlight each item on a page (check this)

Answer (score 6):

If you're writing your own webpage, I'd fix write something with a bit of jquery/javascript.  This is what I've used on mine.

The drawback is that you prevent the default tab-key behavior on the page, which may be a bigger problem for accessibility in some situations.  But I doubt it.

```
var Tab = {};
Tab.i = 1,
Tab.items = 0;

function fixTabulation () {
    /* This can be used to auto-assign tab-indexes, or
    #  commented out if it manual tab-indexes have
    #  already been assigned.
    */
    $('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('tabindex', Tab.i);
        Tab.i++;
        Tab.items++;
    });

    Tab.i = 0;

    /* We need to listen for any forward or backward Tab
    #  key event tell the page where to focus next.
    */
    $(document).on({
        'keydown' : function(e) {
            if (navigator.appVersion.match("Safari")) {
                if (e.keyCode == 9 && !e.shiftKey) { //Tab key pressed
                    e.preventDefault();
                    Tab.i != Tab.items ? Tab.i++ : Tab.i = 1;
                    $('input[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], select[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], textarea[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus();
                }
                if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) { //Tab key pressed
                    e.preventDefault();
                    Tab.i != 1 ? Tab.i-- : Tab.i = Tab.items;
                    $('input[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], select[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], textarea[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    /* We need to update Tab.i if someone clicks into
    #  a different part of the form.  This allows us
    #  to keep tabbing from the newly clicked input
    */
    $('input[tabindex], select[tabindex], textarea[tabindex]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus(function(e) {
        Tab.i = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        console.log(Tab.i);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    fixTabulation();
});
```

This is no perfect solution, but it's quite better than telling all your users to go change their Safari settings in System Prefs, lol.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the following with Safari 5.1.5. I don't know how it works with older versions:

When "highlighting each item on a page" (see answer by graphicdivine) is disabled, you can use that function by pressing Option(alt) + tab.

If you don't (and the option is disabled), Safari will by default tab through all form-fields (like input, textarea, select...). For this fields, it will also accept/regard a tabindex. It will first tab through all form elements with a tabindex (in the order of the given indices) and then through the rest of the form elements in the order of their definition in HTML.

So if you define a tabindex="1" (or 1001) and "3" (or 1003) for two input-elements Safari will first focus this fields and then the others.

Answer (score 3):

For those like me also looking how to enable this in browserstack: simply click the word "Safari" in the top left button of the screen, then you can select Preferences > Advanced > Press tab (as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1914496/11339541)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue and had to implement tab navigation programatically. Luckily found this jquery tabbable plugin https://github.com/marklagendijk/jQuery.tabbable and put it to good use, here's

```
require('../../node_modules/jquery.tabbable/jquery.tabbable');
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(document).keydown((event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 9) {
      window.$.tabNext();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```