# jquery chosen plugin in safari selected by tab key

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-chosen, tabindex

In Safari (tested Windows and MacOS) when tabbing chosen's dropdown `chzn-container-active` class is not added..

Did anybody cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be related to Safari tab logic. Here it is nice answer about this [Is there a workaround to Safari's/Opera's bug that you can't tab through hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292016/is-there-a-workaround-to-safaris-operas-bug-that-you-cant-tab-through-hyperli#answer-2292336)