# Tabindex not working for button

Tags: html

I am using a button to submit my form, but tabindex works on everything, but skips over the button. I can't get the button to highlight using the tab key at all.

```
<button type="submit" class="button" tabindex="11">Submit</button>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: Safari ignores all button tabindexes by default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1914496/142317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to create this issue but my example works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" tabindex="2" />
<input type="text" tabindex="3" />
<input type="text" tabindex="4" />
<button type="submit" tabindex="5">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Is 11 for sure the next tabindex (maybe you are missing one)?
2. What browser are you using?

Edit: This example works for me in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.

Edit 2: Here is a jsfiddle link showing it working fine: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cS9dr/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" tabindex="11" value="Submit">
```